# Need a component for the Column grouping - Outsystems

Tags: javascript, jquery, outsystems

I need to group-by a couple of columns, so is there any component with which I can achieve this?

[image]

What I need is that the column 2 has values that can be added/removed dynamically. So, is there any component which can solve this problem of adding/removing rows and columns under column 2 dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *structure* with the fields you're interested in getting from the database and create an *Advanced Query* that has that structure as output.

In the *Advanced Query*'s SQL you can specify your *group by* clauses like you would do with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or jQuery to dynamically manipulate your tables. There are plenty of examples in the web, such as http://www.amitpatil.me/table-manipulation-with-jquery/.

If needed, you can call an action RunJavaScript, from the HTTPRequestHandler eSpace which will allow you to run the javascript inside a ajax call.